# generate tuple of values from iterables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

If a function gets passed an undefined number of iterables N of arbitrary length M, is there a way to obtain a generator that yield M tuples of size N containing the elements of the passed iterables?

```
def dispatch(*iterables):
    args = ( some kind of generator that involves *iterables)
    for _ in args:
        yield _
```

In other words, if we consider *iterables as an NxM matrix in which each column (function argument) is an iterable is there a way using a generator to yield the rows of the matrix?

Eg:

```
a = [9,8,7,6]
b = 'ciao'
c = iter(range(0,4))

>>> res = dispatch(a,b,c)
>>> res.__next__()
(9,c,0)
>>> res.__next__()
(8,i,1)

etc...
```

furthermore since this function could also take only 1 iterable as argument, the generator should be able to handle the case and output
something like:

```
a = [9,8,7,6]
>>> res = dispatch(a)
>>> res.__next__()
(9,)
>>> res.__next__()
(8,)
```

I tried using zip but it doesn't handle the aforementioned edge case, plus it is kind of slow, which suggest that it probably has to read the whole thing before producing an output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` combined with a `lambda` that pack the arguments:

```
>>> list(map(lambda *x: tuple(x), range(10), range(10), range(10)))
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5), (6, 6, 6), (7, 7, 7), (8, 8, 8), (9, 9, 9)]
>>> list(map(lambda *x: tuple(x), range(10)))
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,)]
```

Your function would be really simple:

```
def dispatch(*args):
    return map(lambda *x: tuple(x), *args)
```

As in your example:

```
>>> a = [9,8,7,6]
>>> b = 'ciao'
>>> c = iter(range(0,4))
>>> list(dispatch(a, b, c))
[(9, 'c', 0), (8, 'i', 1), (7, 'a', 2), (6, 'o', 3)]
```

Comment: @darkpirate, it should perform really well, at the level of map which is pretty perfomant. If you want it to be better, make a function instead of the lambda

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip()` with unpacking:

```
def dispatch(*iterables):
    args = zip(*iterables)
    for _ in args:
        yield _
```

which yields:

```
a = [9,8,7,6]
b = 'ciao'
c = iter(range(0,4))

>>> res = dispatch(a,b,c)
>>> res.__next__()
(9, c, 0)
>>> res.__next__()
(8, i, 1)
```

and for one argument:

```
a = [9,8,7,6]
>>> res = dispatch(a)
>>> res.__next__()
(9,)
>>> res.__next__()
(8,)
```